# Magento 2: change shipping address form fields order

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1.3

Magento 2 having checkout shipping form fields order as its in below image. I need to change fields order in to `Country->State/Province->Zip/Postal Code` as mentioned in same image.

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieve two way.

First,by changing **ui item's** `sortOrder` field value  of those field at **checkout_index_index.xml**.

```
<item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1001</item>
</item>
```

create `checkout_index_index.xml` your theme folder and add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/view/shipping</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1001</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1002</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="region" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1002</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1003</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**You need to changes 1001,1002,1003 value receptive of those fields.**

Comment: Hi Amit, Do you think I need to use `MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate` ?

Comment: I removed this `<item name="component" xsi:type="string">MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/view/shipping</item>` line and working perfect. Thanks