# Magento 2.3.5 : Editing Billing Address and Shipping Address form.html

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, shipping-address, billing-address, magento2.3.5

I am using magento 2.3.5 and require to change the shipping address and billing address field input during checkout, what I required to do is

1. change addresses input field label as per desired

[image]

2. change street address input type from text input to textarea input
3. reposition all input using sequence as below

- Full Name
- Contact Number
- Postal Code
- State ( Dropdownlist )
- City ( Dropdownlist )
- Full Address ( text area )

4. combine first name and last name to become one input which is full name

I already able to do the no 1 which is changing the label through adding the wording list here

**app/design/frontend/MageBig/martfury/layout01/i18n/en_US.csv**

I am also able to do some of the part in no 3 which is by modifying the code at here

**app/code/SR/ModifiedCheckout/Plugin/Block/LayoutProcessor.php**

even though some of the input are able to reposition using orderBy it does not reflect to all field such as street address

I also am having a hard time to accomplish the no 2, I tried creating this file

**app/code/SR/ModifiedCheckout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/form.html**

and fill in using content which I get from its vendor

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/form.html**

and modify as necessary so that it becomes as below

```
<div class="billing-address-form" data-bind="fadeVisible: isAddressFormVisible">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Billing Address'" data-role="title"></div>
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before-fields') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
    <fieldset id="billing-new-address-form" class="fieldset address">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('additional-fieldsets') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <!-- ko if: (isCustomerLoggedIn) -->
            <div class="field save-address">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="billing-save-in-address-book"
                       data-bind="checked: saveInAddressBook" />
                <label class="label" for="billing-save-in-address-book">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Save in address book'"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

if I were to change the id or class I am able to see it is reflected into the billing address form

but I don't understand how this code behave and how do I add in codes to edit the street address input field

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest, this is a long requirement, so you have to work try and run. Please review the below reference link which will help you to achieve your task.

https://inchoo.net/magento-2/frontend/reorder-input-fields-shipping-billing-step-magento-2/

[Magento 2: change shipping address form fields order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223595/magento-2-change-shipping-address-form-fields-order)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783831/checkout-page-shipping-address-form-edit-magento2/45455426

https://www.fmeextensions.com/blog/add-custom-field-magento-2-shipping-address/

I hope this will help.

Please let me know if you are facing any specific issues.
Thanks

Comment: Hi thank you, I am finally able to change all the input field label and make sure the ordering is correct, now the problem I am facing is part in which I need to modify the State text input field to Dropdownlist input field, and also the Full Address text input field to Textarea input field